# Javascript - How to know how much string matched in another string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring

I have been implementing a simple quiz for English. In that, we need to validate answers, which are entered by users in input field. In the current implementation, I am comparing the correct answer with user's answer exactly. Like,

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="answer" />
<button onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var question = "Do you like movies?",
    answer = "No, I don't like movies.";

function validate() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById('answer').value;
    if(answer == userInput) {
      console.log("correct");
    } else {
      console.log("wrong");
    }
}
```

But I don't want validate exactly. Like, ignore case sensitive, commas, apostrophe, etc. For example if user enters,

> i dont like movies

The answer can be correct. I don't know how start and where to start. Anyone please help.

Comment: The essence of the question suggests that you want to verify the subjective answer. Currently, this technology is under development. People are trying to achieve this through AI. So I would suggest writing multiple answers for single question will work for you.

Comment: Because "No! movies are not liked by me" is also a correct answer. So try using an array check the answer is in the array and update the array in course of time.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to strip out all non-word characters and spaces, and compare the lower-case version of each replaced string:

```js
var question = "Do you like movies?",
  answer = "No, I don't like movies.";

const normalize = str => str
  .replace(/[^\w ]/g, '')
  .toLowerCase();
function validate(userInput) {
  const noramlizedInput = normalize(userInput)
  const noramlizedAnswer = normalize(answer);
  if (noramlizedInput == noramlizedAnswer) {
    console.log("correct");
  } else {
    console.log("wrong");
  }
}
validate('No i dont like movies');
validate("NO!!!!! I DON''t like movies.");
```

Another option would be to loop through all possible substrings of the `userInput` and figure out which has the most overlap with the desired `answer`, but that's a whole lot more complicated.

An easier option would be to check to see how many overlapping *words* there are:

```js
var question = "Do you like movies?",
  answer = "No, I don't like movies.";

const normalize = str => str
  .replace(/[^\w ]/g, '')
  .toLowerCase()
  .split(/\s+/)
function validate(userInput) {
  const noramlizedInputArr = normalize(userInput);
  const noramlizedAnswerArr = normalize(answer);
  const overlapCount = noramlizedInputArr.reduce((a, word) => (
    a + Number(noramlizedAnswerArr.includes(word))
  ), 0);
  console.log(overlapCount);
  if (overlapCount >= 4) {
    console.log("correct");
  } else {
    console.log("wrong");
  }
}
validate('No i dont like movies');
validate("NO!!!!! I DON''t like movies.");
validate("i dont like movies.");
validate("Yes I like movies.");
```

Comment: It fails the condition asked in the question

Comment: @CertainPerformance, I will integrate code with my web app. If it works and If I get sufficient reputation I will raise my hand, tick your answer and upvote you.

Comment: @DhananjaiPai See edit, I think counting the number of overlapping words could work

Comment: @CertainPerformance validate("No i do like movies."); and validate(No I like movies) will be equated to true regardless of the incorrect intent. The second algorithm is actually wrong. I had already upvoted the first code for the effort.

Comment: @Dhananjai Pai: Also matters whether one writes `dont` or `do not`. If one writes `Nah, I do not enjoy movies` it fails the same as `Yes`. I would suggest multiple choice in the end, which solves the issue how every user can write an answer differently.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in simply catching spelling errors and small variations, a standard metric is called edit distance or [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). This is a count of the minimum number of deletions, insertions, or substitutions you need to change one text into another. Strings like "No I don't like the movies" and "No I don't like the moveys" will have small edit distances.

Here's a quick and dirty recursive edit distance function that will give you an idea:

```js
function validate(text, pattern) {
  // some simple preprocessing
  let p = pattern.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]+/ig, '')
  let t= text.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]+/ig, '')

  // memoize recursive algorithm
  let matrix  = Array.from({length: t.length + 1}, () => [])

  function editDistance(text, pattern, i = 0, j = 0){
    if(i == text.length && j == pattern.length) return 0
    if(i == text.length) return pattern.length - j
    if(j == pattern.length) return text.length - i   
    let choices = [
        (matrix[i+1][j+1] || (matrix[i+1][j+1] = editDistance(text, pattern, i+1, j+1))) + (text[i].toLowerCase() === pattern[j].toLowerCase() ? 0 : 1),
        (matrix[i+1][j]   || (matrix[i+1][j]   = editDistance(text, pattern, i+1, j))) + 1,
        (matrix[i][j+1]   || (matrix[i][j+1]   = editDistance(text, pattern, i, j+1))) + 1
    ]
    return  Math.min(...choices)
  }
  return editDistance(t, p)
}

// similar strings have smaller edit distances
console.log(validate("No I dont lik moves","No i dont like movies"))

// a little less similar
console.log(validate("Yes I like movies","No i dont like movies"))

// totally different
console.log(validate("Where is the bathroom","No i dont like movies"))

// careful -- small edit distance !== close meaning
console.log(validate("I do like tacos","I don't like tacos"))
```

Picking a minimum acceptable distance works pretty well for matching strings with small typos. Of course, if you are trying to gauge user intent, none of these simple hues tics will work. Strings like "I love tacos" and "I loath tacos" have a small edit distance and you can't tell that they mean the opposite without knowledge of the language. If you need to do this level of checking you can try using a service like `Watson Conversation` that will return user intents to input.